# SQL query for grouping monthly period ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having some trouble building a query that will group my items into monthly ranges according to whenever they exist in a month or not. I'm using PostgreSQL.

For example I have a table with data as this:

```
Name    Period(text)
Ana     2010/09
Ana     2010/10
Ana     2010/11
Ana     2010/12
Ana     2011/01
Ana     2011/02
Peter   2009/05
Peter   2009/06
Peter   2009/07
Peter   2009/08
Peter   2009/12
Peter   2010/01
Peter   2010/02
Peter   2010/03
John    2009/05
John    2009/06
John    2009/09
John    2009/11
John    2009/12
```

and I want the result query to be this:

```
Name    Start     End
Ana     2010/09   2011/02
Peter   2009/05   2009/08
Peter   2009/12   2010/03
John    2009/05   2009/06
John    2009/09   2009/09
John    2009/11   2009/12
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an aggregation problem, but with a twist -- you need the define the groups of adjacent months for each name.

Assuming that the month never appears more than once for a given name, you can do this by assigning a "month" number to each period and subtracting a sequential number.  The values will be a constant for months that are in a row.

```
select name, min(period), max(period)
from (select t.*,
             (cast(left(period, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(right(period, 2) as int) -
              row_number() over (partition by name order by period)
             ) as grp
      from names t
     ) t
group by grp, name;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8c0aa/3) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating this.

Note: duplicates are not really a problem either.  You would jsut use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: I knew there was a better/shorter way to write this! I tried the `row_number() - something` thing but couldn't find the right way to express the "something".

Comment: cool, do you think performance wise it will be faster than recursive one?

Comment: @RomanPekar . . . Yes.  The performance of recursive CTEs is usually worse than equivalent queries that do not use them.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is an easier way (there probably is) but I can't think of one right now:

```
with parts as (
  select name, 
         to_date(replace(period,'/',''), 'yyyymm') as period
  from names
), flagged as (
  select name, 
         period, 
         case 
           when lag(period,1, (period - interval '1' month)::date) over (partition by name order by period) = (period - interval '1' month)::date then null
           else 1
         end as group_flag
  from parts
), grouped as (
  select flagged.*, 
         coalesce(sum(group_flag) over (partition by name order by period),0) as group_nr
  from flagged
)
select name, min(period), max(period)
from grouped
group by name, group_nr
order by name, min(period);
```

The first [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) (`parts`) simple changes the period into a date so that it can be used in an arithmetic expression.

The second CTE (`flagged`) assigns a flag each time the gap (in months) between the current row and the previous is not one.

The third CTE then accumulates those flags to define a unique group number for each consecutive number of rows.

The final select then simply gets the start and end period for each group. I didn't bother to convert the period back to the original format though.

SQLFiddle example that also shows the intermediate result of the `flagged` CTE:
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8c0aa/2

Comment: Nice work but not quite there, you'll get three entries for Peter at the turn of the year.

Comment: good one, I think it could work incorrectly because 201001 - 1 <> 200912. You have to use actual dates and then it will work :)

Comment: @RobertBain: yes, you are right! I need to change the period to a real date to get the proper arithmetic rules. See my edit

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . You don't actually need "real" dates.  You can use a month counter, with the expression `cast(left(period, 4) as int) * 12 + cast(right(period, 2) as int)`.  However, you might like my solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you are right. I like your solution *much* better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Well one of the common ways to do this could be recursive SQL:

```
with recursive cte1 as (
    select
        "Name" as name,
        ("Period"||'/01')::date as period
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select
        c.name, c.period as s, c.period as e
    from cte1 as c
    where not exists (select * from cte1 as t where t.name = c.name and t.period = c.period - interval '1 month')

    union all

    select
        c.name, c.s as s, t.period
    from cte2 as c
        inner join cte1 as t on t.name = c.name and t.period = c.e + interval '1 month'

)   
select
    c.name, to_char(c.s, 'YYYY/MM') as "Start", to_char(max(c.e), 'YYYY/MM') as "End"
from cte2 as c
group by c.name, c.s
order by 1, 2
```

I'm not sure about performance of this one, you have to test it.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/304e6/16)</kbd>**